# Synchronizing large datase from a REST API

Tags: rest-api, batch, callout

For a synchronisation I need to import a somewhat large dataset from a REST API. There around 30k records and the API I consume supports pagination. 
What would be the best approach to retrieve these records and not kill the API with 1000 parallel requests. 
I've looked at batching, but that depends on SF records.
I've looked at Chaining Asynchronous Callouts but that only works for VF pages (if it works)

Is there a mechanisme for this I can use?

Comment: Batch job can be run on strings, not only on Salesforce objects. If your api URL is like <some.url/route>/take=<amount>&skip=<amount>, then you can create array of those, and start batch on them

Comment: Yes, I thought of something like that, but in practice the batches would still fire almost simultaneous, so it wouldn't be different from future calls.

Comment: Batches will run one by one, not in parallel

Comment: @kurunve you are right; but I opted for queue's in the end.

Answer (score 1):

The best option for me turned out to be chaining Queueable Jobs. There are no limits on how many recursions you can do so that suited me.